# binary search function finishing without returning int

Tags: c, compiler-errors, binary-search

I have looked through this function over and over and cannot figure out why I am getting this warning/error when trying to compile the code. The compiler I use runs with -Werror so I am not sure if it is a warning or an error, but the error I am getting is:

error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]

Here is my function

```
int binarySearch(int key, int array[], int min, int max)
{
    //Check if there is value is not found
    if(max < min)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        //find midpoint
        int midpoint = (min + max) / 2;

        //Run recursive steps
        if(array[midpoint] < key)
        {
            binarySearch(key, array, midpoint + 1, max);
        }
        else if(array[midpoint] > key)
        {
            binarySearch(key, array, min, midpoint - 1);
        }
        else
        {
            return midpoint;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't just call binarySearch you need to do somthing with its return value.  Maybe you want to say `return binarySearch(..)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `array[midpoint] < key` or `array[midpoint] > key`, you call `binarySearch` recursively and then fall off the end of the function without specifying a return value.  You presumably want to return the value returned by the recursive calls in those two branches, e.g.

```
return binarySearch(key, array, midpoint + 1, max);
```

(To answer your other question, the compiler diagnostic would have been a warning if `-Werror` wasn't set, but the warning indicates a bug in the code, which is of course why `-Werror` is generally a good idea.)

Comment: From man gcc, under -Wreturn-type: "Also *warn* (emphasis-added) about any "return" statement with no return value in a function whose return type is not "void" (falling off the end of the function body is considered returning without a value)".  -Werror is what makes it an error.